# Echo multidimensional array in a html table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am having a multidimensional array with same values like this,

```
[documents] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
            (
                [doc_id] => 3
                [doc_type] => driving_licence                   
                [expiry_date] => 2015-11-26
                [added_date] => 2015-11-16
            )

    [1] => Array
            (
                [doc_id] => 3
                [doc_type] => driving_licence
                [expiry_date] => 2015-11-26
                [added_date] => 2015-11-16
            )

)
```

So now I need to echo this array in a html table with single `<tr>`.

This is how I tried it :

```
foreach ($userData as $key => $value) {
    $i=0; 
    foreach ($value['documents'] as $k => $v) {
        $i++; 
        $html  = "<tr>\n"; 
        $html .= " <td class='center'>{$i}</td>";
        $html .= " <td>{$v['doc_type']}</td>";
        $html .= " <td>{$v['expiry_date']}</td>";
        $html .= " <td>{$v['added_date']}</td>";
        $html .= "</tr>\n"; 

        echo $html; 
    }
}
```

But its repeating table `<tr>` with same values.

Can anybody tell me how to avoid this? 
Thank you.

Comment: It's the same data because your array contains 2 elements that are identical.

Comment: It seems like you want to remove duplicate values. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/307674/3933332

Comment: @Darren, yes it has same data. how I detect identical data when echoing?

Comment: @user3733831 Do what Rizier commented. (Do it before you start echoing your data out)

Comment: @Darren, can you show me an example for how to do it? I am still confused how I used it. Thank you.

Comment: @user3733831 [See Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34583918/2518525).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583825/echo-multidimensional-array-in-a-html-table?noredirect=1#comment56913181_34583825), here is an example for you.

```
$userData = $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $userData)));

foreach ($userData as $key => $value) {
    $i=0; 
    foreach ($value['documents'] as $k => $v) {
        $i++; 
        $html  = "<tr>\n"; 
        $html .= " <td class='center'>{$i}</td>";
        $html .= " <td>{$v['doc_type']}</td>";
        $html .= " <td>{$v['expiry_date']}</td>";
        $html .= " <td>{$v['added_date']}</td>";
        $html .= "</tr>\n"; 

        echo $html; 
    }
}
```

That will give you a table with **1** `<tr>` row.

Comment: Copy and paste work for this line `$userData = $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $userData)));
`

Comment: I tried it removing `$input` like this `$userData = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $userData)));`. but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @user3733831 Change it to - `$userData['documents'] = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $userData['documents'])));`

Answer (score 0):

this is the way i would do what you are trying to do:

```
 $movies = array 
   (
      array('Office Space' , 'Comedy' , 'Mike Judge' ),
      array('Matrix' , 'Action' , 'Andy / Larry Wachowski' ),
      array('Lost In Translation' , 'Comedy / Drama' , 'Sofia Coppola' ),
      array('A Beautiful Mind' , 'Drama' , 'Ron Howard' ),
      array('Napoleon Dynamite' , 'Comedy' , 'Jared Hess' )
   );

   echo "<table border=\\"1\\">";
   echo "<tr><th>Movies</th><th>Genre</th><th>Director</th></tr>";
   for ( $row = 0; $row < count($movies); $row++ )
   {
      echo "<tr><td>";
      for ( $column = 0; $column < count($movies); $column++ )
      {
         echo $movies[$row][$column] ;
      }
      echo "<td></tr>";
   }
```

Comment: using for with count is really primitive, foreach is better

Comment: @PhiterFernandes what is your evidence for `for` being more primitive out of curiosity?

Comment: You don't need to use a counter to retrieve data, also it uses both keys and values easily. Also the `for` described in the answer will check for the size of the array in every loop. Foreach wouldn't do it.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Easier isn't necessarily more advanced, and as described in the answer the `count` can be repositioned before the iteration so it's not being run in every iteration, so I think one could argue easier, but I don't think `for` is primitive/obsolete. I think either iterator is fine depending on the task it's being applied to.

Comment: To iterate trough strings it's obviously better. For is a good loop of course but not to iterate trough strings.